# ng-model inside ng-repeat is losing focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my JavaScript, I have

```
$scope.newQuestion = {
  answers: []
};
```

My HTML is

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="answer in newQuestion.answers">
  <div class="input-field col m12">
    <input id="answer{{ $index }}" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="newQuestion.answers[$index]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I type something, it loses focus in the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to do:

`<div class="row" ng-repeat="answer in newQuestion.answers track by $index">`